# Selenium Webdriver JAVA - Unable to select option from dropdown menu (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium

I have currently hit a stumbling block when trying to simply pick an option from a dropdown menu whilst automating a website.

Here is a snippet of the HTML:

```
<select id="alarm-dropdown" name="alarm-dropdown" data-bind="value: AlarmCode" data-ga-category="CarInsurance_YourVehicle_VehicleDetails_FittedWithAnAlarm" data-ga-action="Selected" data-ga-label="CarInsurance_YourVehicle_VehicleDetails_FittedWithAnAlarm">
   <option class="" selected="" disabled="" value="">Please select...</option>
   <option class="" id="alarm-dropdown-99991" value="99991">Factory Fitted Thatcham Approved Alarm/Immobiliser</option>
   <option class="" id="alarm-dropdown-99992" value="99992">Factory Fitted Thatcham Approved Alarm</option>
   <option class="" id="alarm-dropdown-99993" value="99993">Factory Fitted Non-Thatcham Alarm/Immobiliser</option>
   <option class="" id="alarm-dropdown-99994" value="99994">Factory Fitted Non-Thatcham Alarm</option>
   <option class="" id="alarm-dropdown-#F" value="#F">Factory Fitted</option>
   <option class="" id="alarm-dropdown-#N" value="#N">None</option>
</select>
```

Here is my current code: -

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alarm-dropdown")));
    select.selectByValue("Factory Fitted Non-Thatcham Alarm");
```

I have tried XPATH/ID/CSS

Comment: I would think you need to use a **value** in the `selectByValue()` method - you are giving it the text instead. Instead of `Factory Fitted Non-Thatcham Alarm` use `99994`.

Comment: Thanks for reply...
Yea, I tried that originally as well..
I think its when im trying to identify the top level dropdown box...
So strange...
I dont seem to be able to "Get to" the available options in the dropdown...
Driving me mad!
Cheers
Steve

Comment: Are you getting any errors like `NoSuchElementException` etc?

Comment: Yea best I have got in the console is: -

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .\/html\/body\/div\[3\]\/div\[2\]\/article\/div\[4\]\/section\/section\[1\]\/div\/ol\/li\[4\]\/ol\/li\[2\]\/label\[1\]\/span\[1\]
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: I have resolved it....
I really dont like using the Xpath but in this case it seems the only viable option...
Please see attached code: - 

  `element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"alarm-dropdown\"]"));
  element.click();
  
  Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alarm-dropdown")));
  select.selectByValue("#F");`

Thanks guys
Steve

Answer (score 1):

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("alarm-dropdown")));
select.selectByValue("99994");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@id='alarm-dropdown']/option[@value='99994']")).click();
```